# Mouse moving while unattended, how can I check for intrusions

Tags: ubuntu, detection, intrusion

A few hours ago, I spotted my unattended mouse moving and seeming to click on tabs. I promptly rebooted my system and removed Teamviewer (it's the only remote connection app that I have installed), Remmina, expressvpn, and a whole bunch of other apps that I no longer use.

Is there anywhere or a way that I can check for intrusions, remote logons to my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)?

Comment: Teamviewer would have had the logs you needed to find out.

Comment: If the mouse looked like it was being deliberately moved by a person it's a fair suspicion that you've been compromised, but if not and it looked erratic it could easily be an error. Perhaps it's a buggy driver.

Answer (score 1):

If the intrusion came from one of the remote desktop apps, then the logs you need would be in their logs. Since you uninstalled them, you may have wiped those logs.

Without knowing how exactly the intrusion occurred, or if it actually occurred, there is no simple answer to this. You would need to check all the logs associated with remote connections (SSH, VNC, etc.). And that's not something we can help with here.

Next time, don't reboot and uninstall, just remove/disable the network connection so that you can preserve the data you need to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Opening your shell and running `ss` will give you information on your system sockets at that point in time. Most importantly it will show you the addresses of other computers yours is connecting with. You may see a few and usually they are harmless, such as repository servers, but not always. Using [this](https://www.ipvoid.com/ip-blacklist-check/) you can get information about each one to check.

This may not always be the gospel truth as to whether your system was intruded on. You could still be compromised in some way or the threat actor simply wasn't connected to your computer when you ran it. However, this still certainly helps.

Comment: `ss` is not so useful once the machine has been rebooted, though.

Answer (score 0):

Log files may be still be available in your home directory - by googleing around I found one possible location: ~/Library/Logs/TeamViewer/ ([source](https://superuser.com/a/635225))
otherwise I would look in /var/log, maybe use grep + "teamviewer" to parse the files and try to find relevant logs.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a terminal open in the background while you use the laptop (`sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog`) to monitor for any suspect activity. But…

Run rkhunter and chckrootkit - I’ve encountered system intrusions that do not produce any log output, suggesting a kernel level compromise.

Check running system services for anything abnormal.

If you find anything suspect consider taking a forensic backup of your hard drive, otherwise reformat your hard drive and re-install Ubuntu with LVM encryption enabled.  Also flash your laptop firmware, if you can prior to reinstall.

Also, check for open ports.